# Error: namespace "boost" has no member "lexical_cast"?

Tags: c++, boost, include

Even though I have this include:

```
#include "boost\lexical_cast.hpp"
```

This line won't compile:

```
int versionInt = boost::lexical_cast<int>(version);
```

When I put to cursor over lexical_cast, it shows "Error: namespace "boost" has no member "lexical_cast"". What is the problem?

Both lines are in the same .cpp file by the way.

Edit: When I compile, it writes: 1>c:\users\mickaël\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\Spirit Arena\Spirit Arena\boost\lexical_cast.hpp(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory

Edit: For some reason, include < fstream > won't work too... All aditional headers I uncluded before lexical_cast did work.

Edit: I wrote the "#include "boots\lexical_cast.hpp"" line as the directory were being copied into my project's folder. Perhaps it has to do with this?

Comment: Does your include path contain the header? Does the file **compile**?

Comment: `#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"`

Comment: I copied the boost folder into my project's folder. There is lexical_cast.hpp into the folder boost.

Comment: @Fanael this changes nothing.

Comment: @Ferruccio Yes and it still won't work.

Comment: Is there actually a file named `config.hpp` anywhere in `boost`?

Comment: When you say you copied the header, did you just copy and paste the files? The missing config header is a part of boost .config. Which is in a different part of the boost source tree. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: Any success?

Comment: @Grzegorz Yes! I was including the wrong directory. I was including one of the boost sub directory.